# Issue with Service API implementation for finding abstract class implementation

Tags: java

In my java project, I am using Service API implementation (creating a services folder providing implementation in a file inside `META-INF` folder of jar) to load the implementation class for one of the abstract class (`DocumentBuilderFactory`). This mapping has been put in a jar.
There is another jar(Xerces.jar) providing different implementation of the same abstract class.

As per the documentation of DocumentBuilderfactory.newInstance(), It is mentioned that when Service-API comes into picture, for providing the implementation class, it looks for all the available jars having 
`META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` file.

My question is, if two jars providing different implementation of the same abstract class are present (both having `META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` file), which one will be picked at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

If several classes with same package/name are present in a classpath, the first one will be taken into account.